# Redux Reducer build object without function

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I can successfully do the following which allows me to build an object of profiles with userid's as the key - I like this structure as it helps with other parts of the application

```
function profilesMembersResponseConcat(members, newMember) {
    members[newMember.userid] = newMember
    return  members
}

[C.PROFILES_MEMBERS_RESPONSE]: (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    profilesMembersResponse: profilesMembersResponseConcat(state.profilesMembersResponse, payload)
}),
```

Question: Is there a way however to do this without the need for a function. I've tried below but I get an error message: "**Arrow function should not return assignment.**"

```
[C.PROFILES_MEMBERS_RESPONSE]: (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    profilesMembersResponse: state.profilesMembersResponse[payload.userid] = payload
}),
```

Comment: Why not using the function? It seems cleaner and also what you're doing on the second snippet is mutating the current state which is not a good practice.

Comment: good call on the mutating state... I was just interested to see if I could do this without a separate function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your solutions are mutating the object. You'll want to change your assignment to something more like:

```
[C.PROFILES_MEMBERS_RESPONSE]: (state, { payload }) => ({
  ...state,
  profilesMembersResponse: ({...state.profilesMembersResponse, [payload.userid]:payload})
}),
```